# JQuery pass value from a form field to a form field on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass the value entered by a user in a form field from a page called "productDetail" to the form field in a page called "gmap-3".

Now normally, if both fields were on the same page, I'd just do something like :

```
$('#productDetail').live("pagecreate", function() {
    $('#submitPost').tap(function() {
        if ($('#postalFrom').val()== "" || null) {
            var postalCode = $('#postalFrom').val();
            alert("Enter postal code first.");
        } else {
            $('#from').val(postalCode);
        }
    });
});
```

But considering the form field "('#from')" is on the page "g-map3" and not "productDetails", how can I accomplish that ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Ok. I'll try and make it clearer if you can tell me what you don't understand in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when going from one page to another, pass the values with the url e.g.

```
http://example.com?postalCode=11204&fname=john&lname=doe
```

then parse the url with location.search. something like

```
var params = location.search.substring(1,location.search.length).split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++)
{
  var field = params[i].split("=")[0];
  var value = params[i].split("=")[1];
  // process
}
```

EDIT

forgot to get rid of the "?" :P hence the substring(1,location.search.length)

Comment: `prams` should be `params`, other wise it wouldn't work. Nice answer btw!

Comment: Small mistake because of the fast answer, can happen? Haha, youre welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Submit your first form as a GET so the variable appears in the query string. Then on your second form you can simply parse the query string to fetch your value.

`document.location.search` will contain your 'foo=1&bar=2' string

From there you'd use `split()` to covert that into an array:
`var q = document.location.search.split('=');`

Now you have your array of query string parameters and grabbing the data you need to populate your form on page 2 is simple.